# Что-то пошло не так. Попробуйте снова

Tags: дефект, tor

При любой активности - посмотреть комментарии, репутацию, написать комментарий - ответ один: "Что-то пошло не так. Попробуйте снова."

Снова ничего не работает. Что делать?

Comment: Вчера ночью такое один раз произошло когда пытался отправить ответ, обновил страницу и проблема исчезла... Может быть тут есть связь

Comment: Обычно происходит из-за плохого соединения. Кстати, там предупреждение на английском (пару месяцев назад видел, сейчас не знаю)

Comment: Проблема всё ещё имеет место быть? Кто-то может подтвердить ещё?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, у меня такое постоянно бывает, особенно если страница повисит. Если оставить страницу хотя бы на пять минут — все накрывается. Еще периодически просто так бывает, особенно когда голосуешь за комментарии: жмешь раз — "попробуйте снова", два — тоже. Если повезет, на третьем это заканчивается.

Comment: Да, раздражает ужасно. Просто ужас какой-то. На MSE написать, что ли?

Comment: На всякий случай, рекомендую почитать сообщения по метке [tor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tor). Возможно, дело именно в этом.

Comment: Конечно, не обсуждаемое поведение, но у меня теперь (м.б. уже год) очень долго не завршается обновление главной страницы, ждет securepabads, google-analitics и т.п. Вероятно эта проблема связана с блокировкой провайдером ряда адресов. Могу предположить, что у вас проблема из той же серии. Ну, глобальное решение довольно очевидно, хотя и весьма трудозатрано

Comment: Если вы используете Tor, то проблема [нерешаема](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393722/1346379). Если же нет, то укажите это в вопросе.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ автор же вроде не говорил, что использует Tor, может быть не стоит тогда добавлять метку [meta-tag:tor]?

Comment: @Зонтик у модераторов есть некоторые козыри на руках

Comment: @αλεχολυτ и какие же? Раскройте секрет, пожалуйста :)

Comment: @Зонтик подробности [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149637/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ то есть вам виден браузер, с помощью которого пользователь в последний раз заходил на сайт? Вот это да.