# "Не так" продолжается

Tags: дефект

Куда обращаться? Все это - [Что-то пошло не так. Попробуйте снова](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13088/228791) - продолжается. Вопрос вижу, но прокомментировать не могу. За что начислены баллы, посмотреть не могу. Лички тут нет, писать некуда, вопрос - единственное, что могу.

Что делать?

Модераторы, передайте жалобу кому надо, а?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]